A couple questions about check fraud?
I was recently watching some videos about the "Chase Bank Glitch" and I was wondering how much people have made from check fraud. And how how often are people caught for fraud? Why do you think people are convinced that they can get away with fraud? How often is fraud detected? How much do people get away with from check fraud?

"Why do you think people are convinced that they can get away with fraud?"  Because they are stupid and believe what "influencers" on TikTok tell them?

The rest of the question is too broad - you might get an AI search to compile some stats for you

It also is more an economics question (statistics) than a personal finance question (what does it mean for the individual).

And criminals, at least the common variety, are generally folks who can't succeed at anything else.

@DStanley You've misspelled the word "idiots" in your first comment :-)

Most of your questions are impossible to answer, but I can confirm that several banks will temporarily allow check fraud.  Its pretty simple, you deposit either a real or fake check and claim that it is for an amount different on the check.  Many banks make the funds available immediately.
Given that a lot of banks run their software overnight and only on banking days one could have free use of money for quite sometime before accuracy is reflected in the bank balance.  For example a payment I made on Saturday over the recent Labor Day weekend was not reflected until Tuesday afternoon and no checks were involved.  Checks frequently take longer to process.
I feel that there are or will be fines for such check fraud transactions so playing this game will be a long-term losing proposition.  If you seek, in this case, to have a long term relationship with Chase it is not wise to do so.
Now there are plenty that just cannot help themselves to the short term allure of money.  They will  open an account to do this kind of fraud then withdraw all the money.  Plenty of people have done similar things like writing bad checks.  As a commenter pointed out this just stupid.
All of that is a crime. Crime, especially against banks, does not pay.  Serial perpetrators could be facing Federal not local charges.  At the least bad credit and fees will hamper them.
If you do not participate in such fraud, none of this will change your life.  The author of the article you read did his job.  You were interested enough to click on the article and help the author's employer earn some ad revenue.

I feel that there are or will be fines - surely, you misspelled "prison time"?

Thanks. This did partially answer my questions

It isn't so much "temporarily allow fraud" as don't immediately detect fraud." They have to allow some time for processing, and as a result the bad check may not be detected as being bad until some short time after it has been deposited and posted, tentatively, to the customers account. They generally do catch up with it after a couple of days and reverse that tentative transaction. See other questions for discussion of how scammers may attempt to use that delay to persuade people to send them real money before the check bounces.
